# Copy content from a Word document to another with the style

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I want to copy the content of a section in a Word document to a new document.

I do this to copy :

```
var docPath = @"C:\temp\myDoc.docx";
var doc = word.Documents.Open(FileName: docPath, ReadOnly: true);
var emptyDoc = word.Documents.Add();

doc.Sections.First.Range.Copy();
emptyDoc.Sections.First.Range.Paste();
```

This works well to copy content, but the style is not the same. How can I copy the complete section and have it rendered exactly the same way in the new document ?

If there is a better solution involving the OpenXML SDK instead of VSTO, I can take it.

Comment: Maybe you need to copy the style definitions somehow?

Comment: Probably, but I have no idea how to do it. I don't see how I can copy doc.Styles or doc.StyleSheets

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't know how to know that either. Perhaps .PasteSpecial() with wdPasteRTF or wdPasteHTML? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdpastedatatype.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You will find it much easier to automate Word if you do things manually first. That way you can get a better understanding of the various options available etc. You can also record a macro which will often, though not always, provide the answer.

In this instance you need to automate selecting 'Keep Source Formatting' from the context toolbar that appears after pasting. The code you need for that is:

```
emptyDoc.Sections.First.Range.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
```